# Does anyone have the monthly data export and import of Russia?

Tags: data-request, economics, russia

I am looking for data regarding the export and import of Russia during the recent 3 months monthly. I am wondering if anyone can give me a hint

Comment: https://www.wsj.com/articles/russia-blocks-economic-data-hiding-effect-of-western-sanctions-11650677765